# Default app for home isn't cleared when installing a new launcher app via ADB

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, adb

When I download a new launcher and install it, the next time I hit home, I'm presented with a dialog to choose which application to launch from the home button.

I'm working on my own launcher app, and when I install it from ADB, it doesn't clear the default and give me the prompt when I hit home the next time.  It shows up if I clear the default manually, but simply installing it doesn't clear the default the way it does when I install apps from the play store.

So, basically, what's clearing the default app when you install (or even update) an app, and how can I make my app do it.  I'm not trying to force it to be the default, I just want my installation to reset the default and allow me to choose again.

Comment: Try installing it by some means other than `adb`, such as by uploading it to DropBox and downloading it via the DropBox client. My guess is that the `adb` install mechanism is the source of your difficulty.

Comment: That did it.  I was trying to streamline my dev process so anytime I installed a new build from ADB, I could just hit home to test it even if I had a launcher set to the default.  Thanks, though.  I swear you're always the one to answer any android question I have. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing apps via `adb` is convenient, but it does bypass a few things. The most visible is that it bypasses the whole permissions-confirmation screen that you would ordinarily get on install, if your app requests permissions. It also does not clear the preferred app for any given `<intent-filter>` you may have, such as one for the home screen launcher.

For testing those things, the easiest solution is to download your app from "teh interwebs", and perhaps the easiest way to do *that* is to toss your app up on DropBox and download it through their client. Any Web site that has the right MIME type for APK files (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`) will do, though. Note that you will need to have checked the "yes, yes, I'd like to be able to get apps from places other than the Play Store, for crying out loud" checkbox (in Developer Options or Applications in Settings, depending on Android OS release).

> I swear you're always the one to answer any android question I have. =)

Now, now, this is supposed to be a "family-friendly" developer resource. Please don't swear.

:-)